# Postgres query function

Tags: postgresql

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.getappointmentwithfilter(
    userid integer,
    periodid integer)
    RETURNS TABLE(user_id integer,
                   scheduleid integer,
                  member_id varchar,
                  appoinmentdate timestamp, 
                  membername character varying
                  ) 
    LANGUAGE 'plpgsql'
    
AS $BODY$
BEGIN
      RETURN QUERY
        SELECT 
            a.userid ,
            a.schedule_id,
            a.memberid,
            a.appoinment_date,
            p.name
             
        FROM 
            member_appointment_details a
        LEFT OUTER JOIN 
            patients p 
        ON 
            p.patientid=a.memberid
        WHERE 
            a.userid=userid 
        AND
           CASE 
              WHEN periodid = 1 THEN
                 date(a.appoinment_date) = date(now())
              WHEN periodid = 2 THEN
                 date('week',a.appoinment_date) = date('week',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
              WHEN periodid = 3 THEN
                 date_part('month',a.appoinment_date) = date_part('month',CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) 
              ELSE
                userid=usrid::integer   
              END
END;
$BODY$;
```

I want to have case for date week month in this function. I tried like this but got error!

Comment: Please clarify what you want to achieve and show the complete error message.

Comment: ';' is missing after the first end

Comment: Reformatted the query to make @Edouard point even clearer.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.